# jenkins pipeline declarative syntax retry with regex

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I see there is option to retry failed build `options { retry(3) }`. I was using navigator plugin with regex to retry only if regex matches, but it doesn't support pipeline.

Is there way to retry only if matches regex in console logs or error, if not can I put random time delay to retry?